# Fetch subset from a superset using Java Streams

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

I have a requirement to fetch the sublist from a given super list as explained below.

Let's say I have a super list of "Person" objects as follows:

```
List<Person> personsList = new ArrayList<>();
personsList.add(new Person("John", 28));
personsList.add(new Person("Paul", 29));
personsList.add(new Person("Adam", 30));
personsList.add(new Person("Peter", 31));
personsList.add(new Person("Pat", 32));
```

Let the Person class be defined as follows:

```
class Person {
    public String name;
    public int age;

    public Person(String name, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return name + ": " + age;
    }
}
```

Given a sub list like this:

```
String [] names = {"John", "Paul", "Adam"};
List<String> namesList = Arrays.asList(names);
```

I would like to fetch the Person Objects where name is `John`, `Paul` and `Adam`.

I am new to Java streams and this is what I have tried so far to meet my requirement.

```
List<Person> finalList = personsList.stream().filter(p -> namesList.contains(p.name))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(() -> new ArrayList<Person>()));
```

I got the desired result, but I would like to know if there is any other efficient method to achieve this (I am mostly looking at namesList.contains(p.name) as a bit inefficient).

Please let me know if there is a better way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assume it makes no sense to have duplicate names in the array, the best way is to find the name in a [`Set<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Set.html) of names. This is easy to achieve. Convert the array to List and include it in the constructor of [`HashSet<T>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet-java.util.Collection-) as soon as it accepts any collection.

```
String [] names = {"John", "Paul", "Adam"};
Set<String> set = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(names));
```

Now use the Stream-API the same as you tried. Use simply only the static method [`Collectors.toList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#toList--).

```
List<Person> list= personsList.stream()
    .filter(i -> set.contains(i.getName()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The result will contain only `John`, `Paul` and `Adam` persons' objects.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolas. So, my basic idea of using "contains" is still good although I could have used Collectors.toList() then. Also, I believe that's a typo in your answer to say that the result will contain only "Peter" and "Pat" person objects?

Comment: I have edited it. It was my bad of course. :) Stream::filter returns a Stream with elements that match the given Predicate.

Answer (score 2):

Defining the `nameList` as a Set will be more efficient, although if the list only contains 3 names the difference won't really be noticeable.

So something like this:

```
Set<String> namesList = new HashSet<> (Arrays.asList("John", "Paul", "Adam"));

List<Person> finalList = personsList.stream()
                                    .filter(p -> namesList.contains(p.name))
                                    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Note: I have also changed the collector to `toList` since that's what you apparently need.

Comment: Thanks @assylias. So, my basic idea of using "contains" is still good although I could have used Collectors.toList() then.